# Is it possible to find out the startup music of windows 95

Tags: windows

I want to find out the music or wav file which was played when windows 95 default theme is loaded. Is there any way to find that or i have load window 95 first in virtual machine first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1ltR2tCz_o)

Unless of course, you were a die-hard Windows geek back in the days and used one of the many built-in themes which came with customized window open / close sounds!

Ahh .. the old days.

--
Fudge. I **was** going to post several links, but the spam prevention system won't let me.
If you just Google for "Windows 95 startup sound" you'll also find a mp3 of it.

Comment: Thanks man actually i didn't knew that sound is still available in mp3 format. Actually with that sound i have my first computer old memories. By listening to that i got lost in those days. thanks

Comment: Useless trivia, it was written by Brian Eno, his name is in the properties of the file.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought it was composed by Robert Fripp (of King Crimson fame)? Maybe he wrote the Windows 2K or XP startup sound?

Comment: Fripp was vista. too bad, he deserves better.

Comment: @Robert: Language! Put a dollar in the jar! Tsk, tsk. ;-)